# Testing repository return NullPointerException - Unit Testing

Tags: android-studio, unit-testing, kotlin

I'm trying to do testing on a repository using mockito but i got this error
[image: error log]

this is my repository

```
interface DiscoverRepository{
  suspend fun trendingMovie():ResultData<Discover?>
}
```

and here I wrote the implementation

```
class RemoteDiscoverRepository @Inject constructor(private val retrofitServices: RetrofitServices) :
DiscoverRepository {

private suspend fun remote(remote:Response<Discover>) : ResultData<Discover?>{
    val request = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { remote }

    return when(request.code()){
        200 -> ResultData(
            true,
            null,
            request.body()
        )

        else -> ResultData(
            false,
            request.body()?.status_message,
            null
        )
    }
}

override suspend fun trendingMovie(): ResultData<Discover?> {
    return remote(retrofitServices.discover().trendingMovieOfTheDay())
}
}
```

this is retrofitService

```
interface RetrofitServices {
 fun discover(): DiscoverDao
}

class RetrofitServicesImpl @Inject constructor(private val retrofit: Retrofit):RetrofitServices{
  override fun discover(): DiscoverDao {
      return retrofit.create(DiscoverDao::class.java)
  }
}
```

and then my repository testing

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class DiscoverRepositoryTest {
  @get:Rule
  var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

  @Mock
  private lateinit var discoverRepository: DiscoverRepository

  @Mock
  private lateinit var retrofitServices: RetrofitServices

  private lateinit var remote : RemoteDiscoverRepository

  private val dummy = DiscoverDummy.getDiscover()


  @Before
  fun setup(){
      remote = RemoteDiscoverRepository(retrofitServices)
  } 


  @Test
  fun trendingMovieTest() = runBlocking {
    `when`(remote.trendingMovie()).thenReturn(dummy)
    val trending = discoverRepository.trendingMovie()
    verify(remote).trendingMovie()
    assertNotNull(trending)
    assertEquals(dummy.data?.results?.size, trending.data?.results?.size)
  }
}
```

I've been trying to find a solution on the internet, it's been taking a lot of time, please help

Answer (score 0):

ah i solve this problem by creating class fake repository like this

```
class FakeRepository(private val remoteDiscoverRepository:RemoteDiscoverRepository):DiscoverRepository {
 override suspend fun trendingMovie(): ResultData<Discover?> {
    return remoteDiscoverRepository.trendingMovie()
 }

 override suspend fun popularMovie(): ResultData<Discover?> {
    return remoteDiscoverRepository.popularMovie()
 }

 override suspend fun topRateTvShow(): ResultData<Discover?> {
    return remoteDiscoverRepository.topRateTvShow()
 }

 override suspend fun latestMovie(): ResultData<Discover?> {
    return remoteDiscoverRepository.latestMovie()
 }

 override suspend fun latestTvShow(): ResultData<Discover?> {
     return remoteDiscoverRepository.latestTvShow()
 }

 override suspend fun tvPopular(): ResultData<Discover?> {
     return remoteDiscoverRepository.tvPopular()
 }
}
```

and then ini my testing code

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class DiscoverRepositoryTest {
 
 @get:Rule
 var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

 private val remote = Mockito.mock(RemoteDiscoverRepository::class.java)

 private val discoverRepository = FakeRepository(remote)

 private val dummy = DiscoverDummy.getDiscover()



 @Test
 fun trendingMovieTest() = runBlocking {
    `when`(remote.trendingMovie()).thenReturn(dummy)
    val trending = discoverRepository.trendingMovie()
    verify(remote).trendingMovie()
    assertNotNull(trending)
    assertEquals(dummy.data?.results?.size, trending.data?.results?.size)
 }
}
```